# load ESRI map modules with requires js error

Tags: android, cordova, dictionary, requirejs, arcgis-js-api

I have a problem regarding ESRI load with requireJs on Android device.
Everything works on the other platform (Blackberry, iOs, WP8) but I can't load the map on android platform.

this is the code I'm using to Load ESRI's files:

```
require([ "esri/map",
                  "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",   
                  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
                  "esri/geometry/Point", 
                  "esri/SpatialReference", 
                  "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol",
                  "esri/graphic",
                  "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
                  "esri/lang",
                  "esri/geometry/Extent",
                  "esri/dijit/InfoWindowLite",
                  "dojo/domReady!"], 

                  function(Map,
                          ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, 
                          FeatureLayer, 
                          Point, 
                          SpatialReference, 
                          PictureMarkerSymbol, 
                          Graphic, 
                          GraphicsLayer, 
                          esriLang, 
                          Extent, 
                          InfoWindowLite) {
        var MyMap = new esri.Map("mapContainer",{
                 basemap: "topo",
                 center: [ 10, 36], // long, lat
                 logo : false,
                 zoom: 11
               });

                 });
```

And this is the log I got :

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: dojo/domReady!_unnormalized3,dojo/i18n!esri/nls/jsapi_unnormalized4,dojo/has!extend-esri?esri/layers/agscommon_unnormalized5,dojo/has!dom-addeventlistener?:./aspect_unnormalized6,dojo/i18n!dojo/cldr/nls/gregorian_unnormalized7,dojo/has!extend-esri?esri/tasks/QueryTask_unnormalized8,dojo/has!extend-esri?esri/tasks/RelationshipQuery_unnormalized9,dojo/has!extend-esri?esri/tasks/StatisticDefinition_unnormalized10,dojox/gfx/renderer!_unnormalized11,dojo/i18n!dojo/cldr/nls/number_unnormalized12,dojo/i18n!esri/nls/jsapi_unnormalized13,dojo/selector/_loader!default_unnormalized14,dojo/has!host-browser?dom-addeventlistener?:../on:_unnormalized15

http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout:1748
```

Does anybody has an idea about this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to put a modulename in your function after InfoWindowLite in the form `function(Map,... InfoWindowLite, ready) {...`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was using ESRI version 3.7, I changed it with ESRI version 3.9 and it works like a charm now.

So It was version issue related to the has.js module. But if you'll have a such problem in loading modules timeOut throughout **requireJs**, you can add this attribute to the **require.config**.

> urlArgs: "bust=" +  (new Date()).getTime(),

It helps solve the problem.